# MYSQL insert comma separated values into separate fields?

Tags: php, mysql

I know its a strange question, but I have one input field that does a live search for locations. The final value is displayed like this:

`State,Suburb,Post Code`

`NSW,Sydney,2210`

What I need to do now is split the three values into single values and update them into my separate fields for one row.

I don't want to update multiple rows but just one.

e.g.:

`fields ( state | suburb | postcode )`
`values ( NSW   | sydney | 2210     )`

What php commands would I use to split those commas off and create single $values for each item?

Comment: you can't split three values into single value. but you may split single value into three values. please consider rewriting your question.

Answer (score 2):

Use explode on the string.

```
$values = 'A,B,C,D';
$values = explode(',', $values);
```

Each item can then be accessed from an array indexed from 0.

Answer (score 1):

```
$val = "NSW,Sydney,2210";
$valArr = explode(",", $val);
$query = "UPDATE MyTbl SET State = '$valArr[0]', Suburb = '$valArr[1]', Post_Code = '$valArr[2]' WHERE ...";
```

Answer (score 0):

The easiest way I think, see the manual for [`explode`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.explode.php):

```
$result_array = explode(',', $your_variable);
```

Answer (score 0):

`list($state, $suburb, $postcode) = explode(',', $value);`

Answer (score 0):

Would this work?

```
$header = "State,Suburb,Post Code"
$items = explode(",", $input)
$output = implode("|", $items)
```

so the output would become `State|Suburb|Post Code`

to access each value separately, you can use `$items[0]`, `$items[1]` ..

```
$data = "NSW,Sydney,2210"
$items = explode(",", $input)
$output = implode("|", $items)
```

so the output would become `NSW|Sydney|2210`